# iText - export PDF - unbalanced begin end text operators

Tags: java, pdf, itext

There are 2 ways of creating PDF files programmatically using iText:

1. using high-level objects such as `Paragraph`, `Chunk`, etc
2. using low-level functionality. this is dome using `PdfContentByte` class.

The second way uses `beginText` and `endText` before and after each new data insertion.

Does the first need to do it too ? Does it use `beginText` and `endText` ?

I'm using the first way, and I'm getting an unbalanced begin end text operators exception.

How could it be ?

Answer (score 2):

## Analysis

If we look into iText API:

> [PdfContentByte](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfContentByte.html) is an object containing the user positioned text
>   and graphic contents of a page. It knows how to apply the proper font
>   encoding.
>
> [Chunk](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Chunk.html) is the smallest significant part of text that can be added
>   to a document. Most elements can be divided in one or more Chunks. A
>   chunk is a String with a certain Font. All other layout parameters
>   should be defined in the object to which this chunk of text is added.

PdfContentByte and Chunk (Element) are made for different purposes. They do not have anything in common, nor interfaces, nor superclasses (excluding Object ofc).

## Q/A

> Does the first why do it too ?

It uses begin to start the writing of text and end to finish the writing of text and make the current font invalid.

> does it uses beginText and endText ?

No, Elements like Chunk and Paragraph do not use begin and end. It uses StringBuffer to hold its text value.

> why am I getting 'unbalanced begin end text operators' exception?

If you look at [PdfContentByte's beginText() and endText() sources](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.itextpdf/itextpdf/5.2.0/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfContentByte.java#PdfContentByte.beginText%28%29), you will see, that if we try to begin text when it is not yet finished, or end text when it is not yet began, we will get this exception.

---

Make sure you called document.open() before starting adding any element to it and document.close() when finishing the document.

Comment: JMelnik , you are saying that when using high-level objects such as Paragraph ("The first way") uses beginText and endText to start and finish the writing of text..

I where we are calling those methods ? 
what I'm doing is document.add(Element)
and I'm getting - "unbalanced begin end text operators itext" Exception.. I can't understand from where this come ?

I'm not using PdfContentByte at all.
please assist.

Comment: @johnSmith, high-level Elements do not use beginText and endText. Why didn't you specify the exception in the question, before? Why did you accept my answer, did it resolve your problem?

Comment: Edit your question, so people would see what are your real problem.

Comment: Caused by: com.lowagie.text.exceptions.IllegalPdfSyntaxException: Unbalanced begin/end text operators.
 at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.endText(Unknown Source)
 at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.newPage(Unknown Source)
 at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.carriageReturn(Unknown Source)

Comment: My question is updated.
How it is possible to get the "unbalanced begin end text operators" exception with out using PdfContentByte at all ?

Answer (score 0):

When using high-level objects in iText, you don't need to worry with the `beginText()` and `endText()` methods. Have a look at this Hello World [example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=12).

Comment: I know I don't need to worry about this , I'v already implemented this.
But I wondering about the implementation of this way , does it uses somewhere in its way the beginText and endText  ?

Comment: @johnSmith Please edit your question and add the actual code you are using. Even better, add a small, standalone example that reproduces the problem. Also, if it's not related to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980788/filedownloadactionlistener-throw-exception-on-cancel-pdf-document-downloading), try to make an example that is decoupled from the web form.

Comment: simple example :

   Document document=new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("hello.pdf"));
      document.open();  
      document.add(new Paragraph("Hello Pdf"));
      document.close(); 


Here I'm exporting the pdf  in Addition I'v added download button throw JSF 2.0 the exception occur when the user press this button and right after that pressing the cancel button

Comment: so what is different from your other question then? you should not post the same question multiple times, rather edit the question and add all the relevant information.

Comment: If I stop the process of export in the middle (some exception is thrown) is it possible to set the PdfContentByte.inText value to false ? this will solve my problem i think